# Why does PHP not have an attribute 'const' like C++ does?

Tags: php, c++

Why does PHP not have the moral equivalent to the C++ `const`? I think that this is lacking in the PHP language. Is there a way to simulate the same properties as a `const` object or parameter?

Comment: PHP is a scripting language.  It runs server-side, so you have complete control of your code.  Why do you need a constant variable?

Comment: I may be mistaken since I haven't touched PHP in a while, but I thought PHP had the const keyword.

Comment: I'm not knowing C++, but what about [PHP-constants](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)? @Kheldar Yes it does for [class constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php),for global constants use the `define()`-method as linked above. See also http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Comment: @Jim: do you have less control of your C++ code than you do of your PHP code?

Comment: @Jim: The idea is that some of these programming ideas/constraints save us from ourselves - i.e. prevent or show us when we make things wrong? See OOP for some details - along with type safety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# doesn't do the `const` thing either, and it is a *very* general-purpose language.

I'm a big `const` fan, but understand why scripts in scripting languages tend to not use them:  Scripting languages are great for "running naked through the woods" because it is "fun", and very quick to add new functionality, because you are *not* enforcing serious type-correctness, including `const`.

Perl and Python and Ruby use scalars for a reason, and pass/return arrays for a reason, because it is very easy to initially "grow" the system.  Adding type correctness, including use of `const`, can *really* slow down development iteration.  Those languages were never intended to create "machined type-safe interfaces", and `const` is the first thing you would do *after* you *first* got type-safety.

Comment: The problem with running naking through the woods is that you get splinters in the strangest of places!

Comment: @Ed Heal: Don't you mean most painful?

Comment: C# actually has the _var_ keyword. I work on some codebase that has lots of _goto_ and _var_ sprayed around. It feels like a very shabby dinner in Italy. No idea what I'll find next in my spaghetti

Answer (score 2):

C++ is pretty unique (amongst C-family languages) to have such a notion of `const`. Quite simply, `const` and const-correctness are *hard* and consume time writing apparently repetitive overloads. That means that many languages which are intended to be simple to use- like say, pretty much all of them except C++- simply don't view it as a worthwhile return on complexity.

Comment: I disagree strongly with the idea that const correctness adds development tine.    The time needed to add the const keyword will pay itself back many times over in ensuring that an object that should be considered immutable actually has that property enforced by the language.  The ability to take a const reference to an object is one of the most powerful and useful features of C++.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like [constant class variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) or just [constants](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)?

For [argument pass-by-reference](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference) you can use `&`, but by default all objects in PHP are passed by reference so you only need to use it with basic types (int,float,string,bool,array)

Comment: In C++ `const` means a contract that you are not going to change it. For example you can pass a variable by reference ('&') and then means reduce the overhead. You can also say it is `const` that also means that the function promises not to change that object - i.e only the `const` methods are available to it!

Comment: I'm no C++ literate as you can probably see. There's no such feature in PHP. If you don't want method to change the argument, you pass it a copy (or make it create a clone of object) Passing by reference does not reduce overhead in PHP (at least not in significant way as it does in C++)

Answer (score -1):

PHP does have this.

global constants:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

class constants:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Comment: It is not the same as `const` in C++.